# SSH exec local shell script with options

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I'm new to shell script, currently I have a shell script named `deploy.sh`, it can take some options like -n namespaceName -a appName and so, like the following.

```sh
./deploy.sh -n namespaceA -a appB
```

but when I execute it like the following via SSH, it doesn't work,

```sh
ssh root@$remoteHost  'bash -s' < deploy.sh -n namespaceA -a appB
```

And when I modify the script to accept paramters directly instead of options(like the above), it works fine.

```sh
ssh root@$remoteHost  'bash -s' < deploy.sh namespaceA appB
```

Is there any way to pass options to it?  Anyone can shed some light? TIA.

Comment: Using [getopts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45744569/how-to-handle-bash-with-multiple-arguments-for-multiple-options) should do should the trick for you.  Also if you put `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script , you won't have to call `bash -s` in your command line...

Comment: `ssh root@$remoteHost "./deploy.sh -n namespaceA -a appB"`?

Comment: @Cyrus I've tried that, it dosen't work. It prompts `bash: ./deploy.sh: No such file or directory`, it does exist in the same dir.

Comment: @Jamie_D I AM USING the getopts command in deploy.sh file, and no, it doesn't work neither, ```#!/bin/bash
ssh root@10.100.111.11 deploy.sh -n namespaceA -a appB
``` It says ` deploy.sh: command not found`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
ssh root@$remoteHost  'bash -s' < deploy.sh -- -n namespaceA -a appB
```

The `--` is added to avoid `-n namespaceA -a appB` being taken by ssh command.

Comment: Genius, you made my day bro!!! I've seached it for a long time, had no lcue. And your comment is very clear. Thanks very much.