# Passing array for option to shell script is not working

Tags: bash, shell

i am executing shell script called ./myscript.sh with 2 options like below

./myscript.sh -d /root/ -n "dhoni" "kohli"

first option is -d and value is /root/

second option is -n and values are dhoni and kohli for this in the current example

But each time while executing this script number of names passed to this script for -names option may vary

the code i have written for this is

```
EMPNAMES=("$@")

while getopts "d:n:" arg; do
   case "$arg" in
      d) PATH="$OPTARG"
      ;;
      n)  EMPNAMES="$OPTARG"
      ;;

for arg in "${EMPNAMES[@]}"; do
  echo "$arg"
done
```

it should print
dhoni
kohli

But it is printing
dhoni
/root/
-names
dhoni
kohli

Comment: `sh`, or `bash`? Please tag only for the one you're actually using to run your script: They're two *very* different shells, and the syntax you're using isn't available at all with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: i am using bash

Comment: BTW, using all-caps names for your own variables is bad form -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph: Such names are used for variables meaningful to the shell or other POSIX-specified tools, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use.

Comment: If you're using `bash`, the `sh` tag should be removed.

Comment: ...anyhow, I don't know why you think it should print only `dhoni` `kohli`. That's not what a plain reading of the code *does*.

Comment: ok i will do that , but for the time being shall we concentrate on finding the logic for achieving the required thing

Comment: (f/e, overriding `PATH` will stop your script from being able to run any external programs, because it's changing the PATH variable used to execute other software; if you named in `path` instead, you'd avoid that bug).

Comment: yes , the logic should print dhoni and kohli and my logic is not working fine because of which i have posted the query , if the logic is working why would have been i posted here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164979/discussion-between-sachin-sarangamath-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: dude, there are more questions raised by your code than you're seeing, you're missing relevant issues because you're new. have a little respect.

Comment: @jthil i have respect for everyones valuable time for being spent here

Answer (score 2):

`empnames=( "$@" )` doesn't make sense if you want the array to only contain matches, because you're initializing it to contain *every single argument your script was passed at startup*. Instead, initialize it to start out empty, and append to it every time you find an appropriate argument.

Note that `n:` specifies that *one* argument immediately after `-n` is a name. If you want to specify two names, put `-n` before each of them, as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# set argument list, just as if the script were called with these arguments
set -- -d /root/ -n "dhoni" -n "kohli"

# Initialize your array to start out empty
empnames=( )

while getopts "d:n:" arg; do
   case "$arg" in
      d) path="$OPTARG" ;;
      n) empnames+=( "$OPTARG" ) ;;
   esac
done

for arg in "${empnames[@]}"; do
  echo "$arg"
done
```

...[properly emits](https://ideone.com/7evNVe):

```
dhoni
kohli
```

Comment: thanks for the solution and thanks for ur valuable time for this , but one query , is there any way that i can pass args like                                              set -- -d /root/ -n "dhoni" "kohli" and get the required output

Comment: Not that plays nice with the way `getopts` is supposed to be used. There are some workarounds that are possible, but the better answer is just not to use that convention.

Comment: Here's a question -- what do you want to do with names that don't have *any* flag before them? No `-d`, no `-n`, etc.

Comment: or is there any other way apart from getopts with which i can achieve the required thing

Comment: If you want to roll your own command-line parsing, see [BashFAQ #35](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035). If you're doing that, then in the `-n` case you could just set `empnames=( "$@" ); break` to assign all remaining arguments to that array and exit the loop. But that would mean that `-n` would need to be *after* the `-d`; are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: You might also want [processing command line options with multiple arguments in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394825/processing-command-line-options-with-multiple-arguments-in-bash), or [retrieving multiple arguments for a single option using getopts in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529856/retrieving-multiple-arguments-for-a-single-option-using-getopts-in-bash).

Comment: actually my requirement i am executing shell which has 2 options say -d -n myscript.sh -d /root/ -n dhoni kohli at one time user may execute the script without passing second arguement like myscript.sh -d /root/ and he also my execute script like myscript.sh -d /root/ -n dhoni kohli then i want to store names after -n in one array

Answer (score 1):

```
      n)  EMPNAMES="$OPTARG"
```

is assigning to an array, in bash that defaults to the first element of that array, replacing the `-d` that was there before.

`getopts` options that take an argument only take one, `kohli` is left as a main-body argument.

Comment: thanks for the comment , can u please suggest me how can i get the required output as posted above

Comment: It'd help if you explained the context a bit.  As a first cut at it I'd say lose the `n` option entirely and shift out the options with `shift $((OPTIND-1))`, then just `printf %s\\n "$@"`

Comment: while executing the script i want to pass 2 names for the option -n , this passed names should be stored in an array in the script

Comment: The usual way to do that is to pass both as a single argument and separate them in the arg processing, commas are common, or you could use colon as that's a conventionally-reserved character in paths.  Having one option eat two arguments will violate the Principle of Least Surprise :-)